# EE comments stopped working

Tags: error, javascript, comments

Using EE 2.5.2

I'm not aware of any changes that I would have caused this, however, I'm getting a javascript error.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mysite.com/?ACT=comment_editor". mypage:59
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'CommentEditor'
```

My comment fields are being rendered in the source code (with the correct brackets of course):

```
[script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://mysite.com/?ACT=jquery"][/script]
[script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://mysite.com/?ACT=comment_editor">[/script]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What if you just drop the `type` parameter?

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/?ACT=jquery"></script>
<script src="http://mysite.com/?ACT=comment_editor"></script>
```